# A button designed to send text from a textarea causes the input to not appear

Tags: javascript, html, flexbox

I have an issue with a custom text-area called a math field. I'm currently in a internship building a math search engine and the user will have a query bar in which they can input plain text and LaTeX equations.

The current issue is that the send button when pressed will sometimes cause the input to not appear at the left of the textbox.

This is my first time building a website so I only have about 5 weeks of experience so I'm coming to stack overflow to see if anyone has a intuition on why this is happening.

For anyone who attempts to run the **minimum viable example** enter some text and then press the send button. After that you will either be able to enter text normally or nothing will show up.

The issue I'm facing is that nothing will show up and I don't know why.

I believe that the "contenteditable" attribute may be contributing to this issue as from my recollection that makes the entire content of the element editable meaning that my cursor may be getting stuck there and the input is getting voided.

I really don't have much of an idea why its happening though.

MINIMUM VIABLE EXAMPLE

```js
let airplanesvg = '<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M14.5 0.5L14.9596 0.69696C15.0401 0.509038 14.9981 0.291016 14.8536 0.146447C14.709 0.00187701 14.491 -0.0401102 14.303 0.0404275L14.5 0.5ZM0.5 6.5L0.30304 6.04043C0.130457 6.11439 0.0138614 6.27881 0.00114754 6.46614C-0.0115663 6.65348 0.0817453 6.83214 0.242752 6.92875L0.5 6.5ZM8.5 14.5L8.07125 14.7572C8.16786 14.9183 8.34652 15.0116 8.53386 14.9989C8.72119 14.9861 8.88561 14.8695 8.95957 14.697L8.5 14.5ZM14.303 0.0404275L0.30304 6.04043L0.69696 6.95957L14.697 0.959573L14.303 0.0404275ZM0.242752 6.92875L5.24275 9.92875L5.75725 9.07125L0.757248 6.07125L0.242752 6.92875ZM5.07125 9.75725L8.07125 14.7572L8.92875 14.2428L5.92875 9.24275L5.07125 9.75725ZM8.95957 14.697L14.9596 0.69696L14.0404 0.30304L8.04043 14.303L8.95957 14.697ZM14.1464 0.146447L5.14645 9.14645L5.85355 9.85355L14.8536 0.853553L14.1464 0.146447Z" fill="#2596BE"/></svg>'
let sendnode = `<div  id="send" onClick='emitEvent()' class="ML__virtual-keyboard-toggle" role="button" data-ml__tooltip="Send Message" style="display: flex;">${airplanesvg}</div>`
let textnode = '<div  id="textToggle" class="ML__virtual-keyboard-toggle" role="button" data-ml__tooltip="Toggle Text Mode" style="display: flex;"><svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 17 17" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path d="M14 2v3h-1v-2h-4v12h1.643v1h-4.286v-1h1.643v-12h-4v2h-1v-3h11z" fill="#2596BE" /></svg></div>'
const mf = document.getElementById('textInput');

function setupMathBar() {
  insideBar = mf.shadowRoot
  box = insideBar.querySelectorAll(".ML__container")
  $(box).append(textnode)
  $(box).append(sendnode)

}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  setupMathBar()
});

function emitEvent() {
  bot(document.getElementById('textInput').value)

}

function bot(textInputValue) {
  document.getElementById("textInput").value = ""
  //this function is irrelevant, Its part of the codebase but Im using it to trigger the issue
  return
}

document.getElementById("textInput").addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  //this fires upon the user pressing the enter key while editing in the math-field
  if (e.inputType === 'insertLineBreak') {
    bot(e.target.value);
  }
});
```

```css
#textInput {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #009688;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/mathlive@0.94.8/dist/mathlive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<math-field id="textInput">f(x) = \sin(x+\pi)</math-field>
```

I wouldn't recommend reading the code first, Your best bet to understanding the issue to is to copy all the above into a html file then open it in a browser.

Then try entering some text and pressing the send button and observing the issue I was talking about.

Comment: `mathlive.min.js` is getting an error related to PostMessage. I guess it's not compatible with the Stack Snippet environment.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem without the MathLive library?

Comment: No, the mathlive library defines the <mathfield> tag.

Comment: OK, I've typed in the search field and clicked the send button. What should I expect to see?

Comment: The issue is that occasionally after pressing the send button, input to the text bar is voided even when the text bar is selected. Try pressing the send button and then typing again. It may take a couple attempts for this error to occur.

Comment: When I click the send button it always empties the search field. What is it supposed to do instead?

Comment: That's what `document.getElementById("textInput").value = ""` does.

Comment: The comment says the `bot()` function is irrelevant. But it seems to be the entire problem. It's not using the `textInputValue` parameter.

Comment: This snippet is part of a bigger code base. I didn't change the name of the bot function but it empties the text bar for a new message to be received. The real problem is after pressing the send button you can no longer input text.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce that. I've pressed send at least a dozen times and I could still input text, with both the regular keyboard and the on-screen keypad.'

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when this happens?

Comment: There are no errors in the console and I discovered it only works correctly on chrome. I was initially using firefox but upon switching to chrome the bug was gone so if you want to continue attempting to recreate it firefox is the best bet and thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was only apparent on Firefox but not present on Chrome.